# Strange electrical issue with after market brake lights

Tags: brakes, lights, aftermarket-upgrade, electrical

I've got a 1991 Jeep Wrangler.

About 3 years ago I put LED brake lights on. They worked great until just a couple days ago, when the drivers side stopped working. Shortly after, they started working again with no intervention on my part. They now have stopped  working again.

I can unplug the light and plug it into the passenger side and it works just fine. I have power going to the tips of the connector that go into the light on the drivers side, but it still does not want to work on this plug.

What could be the issue?

Comment: I have been reading up in the automotive forums everywhere, trying to get better backup lights going. I have been seeing that the LEDs are not all they are cracked up to be. Some last what they repute, some don't

Answer (score 2):

An LED unit is more complex than a standard filament bulb.  As such, you can get what you pay for and that's a cheap LED bulb can give less than stellar performance.  I have LEDs on my motorcycles and cars, some with CANBUS and some not, and have had no issues but I buy quality parts, not necessarily the absolute cheapest eBay deal I can find.

During use the device can heat up, especially the super-bright units.  If there is a hairline crack in the circuitry then it will expand when warm and break the circuit (this is maddening when it happens to a coil!).  Given that when a standard bulb is installed the issue totally goes away, this confirms that the vehicle circuitry is fine and the issue is with the LED bulb.